# GET http://0.0.0.0:8080/index.html?age=8&rel= 404 (/Object Not Found)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to see the values entered into the form via console.log, but I am getting this error message.
I am not sure why this is happening. Is it somehow connected to the local server? or is it a JS problem?
 Would appreciate any light that can be shed.
thank you!

this is the JavaScript code (index.js)

```
// Person Constructor
  function Person(age, relationship, smoker){
    this.age = age;
    this.relationship = relationship;
    this.smoker = smoker;
  }

  // UI Constructor
  function UI() {}

  // Event Listeners
  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit',
   function(e){
    const age = document.getElementsByName("age")[0].value,
          relationship = document.getElementsByName("relationship")[0].value,
          smoker = document.getElementsByName("smoker")[0].value
    console.log(age, relationship, smoker)
    e.preventDefault();
   });
```

and this is index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Household builder</title>
        <style>
            .debug {
                font-family: monospace;
                border: 1px solid black;
                padding: 10px;
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Household builder</h1>
        <div class="builder">
            <ol class="household"></ol>
            <form>
                <div>
                    <label>Age
                        <input type="text" name="age">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Relationship
                        <select name="rel">
                            <option value="">---</option>
                            <option value="self">Self</option>
                            <option value="spouse">Spouse</option>
                            <option value="child">Child</option>
                            <option value="parent">Parent</option>
                            <option value="grandparent">Grandparent</option>
                            <option value="other">Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label>Smoker?
                        <input type="checkbox" name="smoker">
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button class="add">add</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <button type="submit">submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <pre class="debug"></pre>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="./index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no such IP address as 0.0.0.0 - this is actually an alias which means "all/any of the IP addresses of your PC". Obviously no browser can connect to "all" IP addresses - you have to specify a real IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You're using `document.getElementsByName("relationship")`, but your relationship element is actually using `name="rel"`; switch that line to `document.getElementsByName("rel")` and you should be good!

You're getting the error message because that line of JS is failing, which means the later `e.preventDefault();` line never executes, which means your form is actually posting. If you check the JS console, you should see an error like `TypeError: document.getElementsByName(...)[0] is undefined`

Note also that for your checkbox, you are right now retrieving the [`value`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-value) attribute, which will always just be the string "on"; you probably want to be using the [`checked`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked) attribute, which will tell you whether or not the box has been checked.